# Evaluating a string as a variable within EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, arangodb

Within EJS I have a string variable that I want to evaluate as a variable within EJS as well. Normally speaking I think one can do `window['variable']` but this doesn't work within EJS. Basically what it would look like in my mind is:

`<% <%- 'concepts' %>.forEach(function(item) { %>`

Whereby concepts is the name of one of the objects I'd like to use within EJS. However, I am aware that nested EJS tags are not a thing. So how does one both evaluate a string as a variable in EJS and also use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems one can simply use `eval` on it and it'll work within EJS as well. So:

`<% eval('concepts').forEach(function(item) { %>`